# Moving cloth object

Tags: animation, cloth-simulation

I'm trying to connect this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5d03tZO0C9g&t=80s to explode a sphere and a moving animation on the same sphere. I animated the sphere first and now I want to let it explode during it moves through the room. The Problem is, that after I put the Cloth on it, the mesh is not moving. You can see the pivot point with the moving arrows move, but not the mesh. How can I fix this? Thank you

Comment: To move object after Cloth sim you should use deform modifiers, such as Armature, Hook, Lattice. Make sure that deform modifier is placed after Cloth in modifier stack

Comment: But how should i use them to make my  animation function again?

Comment: Ah, if you want to move during animation... Then modifiers should be before Cloth and in Cloth's settings animate Pinning vertex group. Modifiers should also affect Pin group (just assign all geometry to new vertex group in edit mode)